# Card View disappearing when image added

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

I am currently making a band app for some work I have and have made a card view which will show the band members along with an image this works fine but after I created it I wanted to add stuff outside the card view and once I add for example an image view the card view and its contents disappears. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     tools:context="com.package.test.band.MainActivity"
     tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_bg_banner" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="150dp"

>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"

    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/member1_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Member 1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/member1_job"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Guitar and Vocals"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/member1_name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/content_memeber1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/member1_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/content_member1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/member2_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="member2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/member2_job"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bass"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/member2_name"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/content_member2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/member2_name"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/content_member2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/member3_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="member3"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/member3_job"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drummer"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/member3_name"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/content_member3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/member3_name"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/content_member3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your linearlayout orientation is horizontal and you make your image match parent width so automatically the cardview will be outside the screen

Comment: Thanks the horizontal thing helped out. the image is now pushing the image far down the screen. any ideas on why that is?